# importing user defined library in redshift UDF

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

Here i am trying to import a library inside my user defined python function in redshift

I have created an library called nltk as follows

```
[CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY nltk LANGUAGE plpythonu FROM 's3://nltk.zip' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=*****;aws_secret_access_key=****';]
```

once created i tried to import this in a function as

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_function (sentence varchar)
    RETURNS VARCHAR STABLE AS $$
    from nltk import tokenize
    token = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    return token $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

tokenize is a sub directory inside nltk library

but when i try to run the function by calling it on a table as

```
SELECT f_function(text) from table_txt;
```

I am getting an error as such

> Amazon Invalid operation: ImportError: No module named nltk. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
>   Details:
>    -----------------------------------------------
>    error:  ImportError: No module named nltk. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
>     code:      10000
>     context:   UDF
>     query:     69145
>     location:  udf_client.cpp:298
>     process:   query0_21 [pid=3165]

Can anyone help me where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: have you used nltk into redshift????

Answer (score 1):

First, there is an obvious problem with your Python code: you are never importing `nltk`, and then calling `nltk.word_tokenize`.

Second, after downloading the `nltk` package, you need to zip the module folder that is inside the package and upload this zip to RedShift.

```
nltk-X.Y.zip
├─ setup.py
├─ requirements.txt
├─ nltk <- This is the folder that should be zipped and uploaded to S3
...  ├─ __init__.py
     ├─ tokenize.py
```

RedShift can only load modules -- your root folder should have an `__init__.py` file.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html

Answer (score 1):

I still struggled with the above instructions, so when I finally found it I thought I would pass along how I got it to work.

First, create your library:

```
create or replace library stem 
language plpythonu 
from 's3://[Your Bucket Here]/stem.zip' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=[aws key];aws_secret_access_key=[aws secret key]';
```

Here is the Stemming nltk zip library I edited (I pulled in the compat to make it self contained), then upload that to S3: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNI6AJdNrJCVThoSXVHY1NyUGM/view?usp=sharing 
In order to use that, I had to edit the **init**.py library to reference the Redshift created UDF Library created above ("Stem").

Then I created my python UDF function in Redshift:

```
create or replace function f_lancaster_stem (text varchar)
returns varchar 
immutable as $$
    from stem import LancasterStemmer
    st = LancasterStemmer()
    return st.stem(text)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

then just call the UDF!

```
select f_lancaster_stem('resting') from dual;
```

Comment: I'm not following what you had to do to init.py to get it to work.